# JMS Serializer Config

Tags: symfony, configuration, yaml, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I am using this in config.yml:

```
# JMSSerializer Configuration
jms_serializer:
    #parameters:
        #jms_serializer.camel_case_naming_strategy.class: JMS\Serializer\Naming\IdenticalPropertyNamingStrategy
    metadata:
        cache: file
        debug: "%kernel.debug%"
        file_cache:
            dir: "%kernel.cache_dir%/serializer"
        auto_detection: true
        directories:
            AppBundle:
                namespace_prefix: "AppBundle"
                path: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/serializer/AppBundle"
```

And this in Entity.Category.yml:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Category:
exclusion_policy: ALL
```

But when i try to send request, i receive this error:

> Expected metadata for class AppBundle\Entity\Category to be defined
>   in /var/www/test/app/config/serializer/AppBundle/Entity.Category.yml.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot about `TAB` at 2 line.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting an incorrect path to your project files with `%kernel.root_dir%`. Make sure that `/var/www/test/app` is the correct path to your project. Check your PHP `__DIR__` constant and try replacing `%kernel.root_dir% with what that says as well as what you think the path should be.

Also, instead of defining your exclusion policy in a config file you should just be able to annotate your entity like so and expose things as needed:

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;

/**
 * Class ExampleEntity
 *
 * @JMS\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class ExampleEntity
{
}
```

JMS annotations are found [here](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations).

Comment: path is correct, how can i do that wihout annotations, using yml?

Comment: What symfony version are you using? If it is 4.0 or up then `%kernel.root_dir%` is changed and the path should be `%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/serializer`. Check out this [post](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/536).

Comment: i am using symfony 3.4